# How to define non-independent random effects in a mixed-effect model?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am looking at how unicorn abundance changes with food quality and I am not sure how to define the random part of the corresponding mixed-effect model (hereafter: MEM).

DATA STRUCTURE: we sampled seven locations over the course of twelve months. For each location at each month we have one value of food quality (continuous predictor). For each location on each month, unicorns were re-counted over four days in a row to account for both unicorn movement and possible sampling error.

THE ANALYSIS: we are using a generalised mixed effect model with Poisson-distributed residuals to account for the fact that the response variable is represented by count data.

THE ISSUE: I want to define the random part of my model to account for both the fact that we have **repeated measures** of unicorn abundance for each month at each location, *and* that there might be a **locality effect** that affects the observed relationship between unicorn abundance changes with food quality.
If I were to create a MEM to account only for locality effect, I'd write it as:

```
lme4::glmer(n.unicorns ~ food.quality
+ (1 + food.quality | locality),
family=“poisson”)
```

If I were to create a MEM to account only for the random effect of sampling time (sampling day in each month nested in sampling month) I believe it'd be:

```
lme4::glmer(n.unicorns ~ food.quality
+ (1 + food.quality | survey_month/survey_day),
family=“poisson”)
```

But how to account for repeated measurements at each locality on each sampling month? I am not sure of the relationship between `survey_month/survey_day` and `locality`. Is `survey_month/survey_day` nested in `locality`? Is it vice versa? Or are the random effects of `survey_day/survey_month` and of `locality` to be treated as separate and independent from each other? I would code the latter as:

```
lme4::glmer(n.unicorns ~ food.quality
+ (1 + food.quality | survey_month/survey_day) + (1 + food.quality | locality),
family=“poisson”)
```

My MEM skills are a bit rusty.

Comment: This could be useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified

Comment: In contrast to the locality, accounting for non-independence of repeated measurements is not a matter of clustering but of autocorrelation. Unfortunately, `lme4` seems to be bad at handling autocorrelations, i.e. it requires extending packages which are either outdated or not very well known. You may want to use `nlme` instead. It's syntax is somewhat different from `lme4` but your model should not be hard to define in that framework, too. Source: [Ben Bolker's braindump on MEM with temporal correlations](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/corr_braindump.html)

Comment: @benimwolfspelz thank you. Unfortunately `nlme` handles autocorrelation but not non-normally distributed residuals, while `lme4` handles non-normally distributed residuals but not autocorrelation (at least, not without some tweaking and hacking that I am not capable of). Package `glmmTMB` might work. An alternative that I am exploring is to use package `ubms`, a sort of happy mix of packages `unmarked` and `lme4`. It uses a similar syntax as `lme4` and uses repeated measures to "perfect" abundance estimates using some magical black box (for me at least).

Comment: For the record, here is information on mixed effects in `ubms`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ubms/vignettes/random-effects.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion, thanks to input from multiple people and [sources](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified), that `survey_month` and `locality` are not nested: every level of `survey_month` is available for each locality, and every level of `locality` is available for each survey month. So, ignoring `survey_day` for the moment, the model would be:

```
lme4::glmer(n.unicorns ~ food.quality
+ (1 + food.quality | locality)
+ (1  + food.quality | survey_month),
family=“poisson”)
```

With regards to `survey_day`, @benimwolfspelz pointed out that "*accounting for [...] repeated measurements is not a matter of clustering but of autocorrelation*". Autocorrelation can be accounted for easily with package `glmmTMB` (see [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html)):

```
# survey_day must be provided to glmmTMB as a factor:
unicorns$survey_day_f <- numFactor(unicorns$survey_day)
levels(unicorns$survey_day_f)

glmmTMB::glmmTMB(n.unicorns ~ food.quantity
                        + (1 + food.quality | locality)
                        + (1 + food.quality | survey_month)
                        + ou(survey_day_f + 0 | locality),
                        family="poisson", data=unicorns)
```

See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519799/temporal-autoregression-in-glmmtmb-what-do-alternative-syntax-forms-mean) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67096534/temporal-autoregression-in-glmmtmb-why-does-it-require-time-as-a-factor) for further details on the syntax for the autocorrelation term and on why I am using `ou()` and not `ar1()` (or just read the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html) more carefully than I initially did).