# Temporal autoregression in glmmTMB: why does it require time as a factor?

Tags: r, mixed-models, autocorrelation, glmmtmb

With regards to autocorrelation, how can `glmmTMB` tell how far apart time steps are if the time sequence must be provided to `ar1()` as a **factor**?

In `glmmTMB`, `ar1` requires timesteps to be evenly spaced and to be coded as a factor (see this [vignette](https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-04-22/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html)). Given a numerical time series `time.steps`, is it enough to recode it as `as.factor(time.steps)` for the model to run correctly? How can `glmmTMB` tell how far apart moments in time are if the time sequence must be provided  as a factor?

Comment: This is quite a question ... ideally each Stack Overflow post should contain exactly **one** question ...  Can you please split this into multiple, more-focused questions? Have you read https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html ? If you have *unevenly spaced* samples you should use the `ou()` covariance structure instead of `ar1`

Comment: @BenBolker I did look at the vignette but clearly not well enough. I ignored the methods requiring coordinates thinking that they were specific to spatial autocorrelation, but of course time is also a coordinate system. My blunder. 
I made this question specific on why ar1() requires time as a factor. The part on alternative ar(1) syntax forms is now here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519799/temporal-autoregression-in-glmmtmb-what-do-alternative-syntax-forms-mean

Comment: Of relevance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918655/glmmtmb-with-autocorrelation-of-irregular-times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it enough to recode it as as.factor(time.steps) for the model to run correctly?

Yes.

> How can glmmTMB tell how far apart moments in time are if the time sequence must be provided as a factor?

The assumption is that successive levels of the factor are one time step apart (the `ar1()` covariance structure does not allow for unevenly spaced time steps: for that you need the `ou()` covariance structure, for which you need to use `numFactor()` to encode the time values).

For a little more detail: the correlation structure for an AR1-structured random effect is

```
1     rho   rho^2  rho^3 ...
rho   1     rho    rho^2 ...
rho^2 rho   1      rho   ...
rho^3 rho^2 rho    1     ...
...   ...   ...    ...   ...
```

where the row/column positions correspond to time steps/levels of the factor. So we really don't need to know anything more than the *order* of the time steps, which is specified by the order of the levels of the factor.